# Any approximation for $1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots + \frac{x^n}{n!}$ for finite $n$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

I want to approximate $1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots + \frac{x^n}{n!}$ for finite $n$, where $n \geq x > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am wondering if there exits tight upper and lower bounds $U(x, n)$ and $L(x, n)$ such that

$$L(x, n) \leq \sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!} \leq U(x, n).$$

A well-known result is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!} = e^{x}$, but how about finite $n$?

Comment: What range of $n$ and $x$ are you looking at? That'll have a substantial impact on best approximations.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks for pointing it out. I re-edited.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific. $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a given; it was more 'do you expect $x\ll 1$, $x\approx 1$ or $x\gg 1$? Will $n$ be of size roughly $x$, larger, smaller, ?'

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Actually, I only know $x$ is general positive real number and $x < n$.

Comment: The bounds that you request have an (almost) trivial answer; $L(x,n)=1$ and $U(x,n)=e^x$ work by convexity of the sum. It sounds like you're looking for something tighter than that, though. This is starting to have a little bit of a feel of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); what's the _root_ problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The problem is equivalent of estimating the incomplete gamma functions: see formulae 8.4.7-8.4.11 [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4).

Comment: It is well known that:  $e^x = \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1 + \frac xn)^n$  But, for finite $n$ it should serve to be one of your bounds.  It is a lower bound for $x>0$ I am not sure if that is also the case when $x<0$

Comment: One not-very-good pair of estimates is $L(x,n)=e^x-\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!},U(x,n)=e^x$. This comes from Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder (for $x \geq 0$). This estimate is decent once $n>ex$ or so.

Comment: @DougM I believe this still technically works for $x<0$ but for large negative $x$ it goes badly even when $n$ is even because you have growth at $-\infty$ whereas you should've had decay.

Comment: @Ian  It gets better when |n|>|x|